# Regex to strip html tags adding an additional character

Tags: jquery, regex

I am having a weird situation where in I am using regex expression to strip down the HTML tags from my text

I have the following text:

```
<div align="center">​test_gautam</div>
```

which on application of the following regex

```
var regex = /(<[^>]*>)/ig;
var CommentText = editor.getValue().replace(regex, "");
```

Gives me

```
"​test_gautam"
```

This looks fine but on careful examination I found out that there is an invisible character between first quote and t. 
Due to this my other regex is failing. 
Does anyone have any idea about how to get rid of this invisible character?

to check the invisible character copy the following text and paste in notepad

```
"​test_gautam"
```

Comment: Doesn't your editor have a method to get the pure text without tags?

Comment: Notepad++ shows no "invisibile char". Also pls tag the programm language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var regex = /(<[^>]*>)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*/ig;`

Should grab anything which isn't a letter/number and comes after the `<`